# Why does the virtual environment in Jupyterlab has access to packages that were not installed?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, python-venv

My question is why I can access pandas in a jupyter notebook even though it was not installed in the used environment.

I created a virtual environment:
`python -m venv ml_skt_book`
I then activated it:
`ml_skt_book\Scripts\activate.bat`
I then installed numpy:
`pip install numpy`
I have three packages now: numpy, pip and setuptools
[image: list of installed packages]

I then link it to the jupyter notebook kernel:
`python -m ipykernel install --name=ml_skt_book`

That worked. I then checked in the command line if numpy works and pandas not. This was successfull.
[image: Environment packages check]

I then opened jupyterlabs:
`jupyter-lab`
started a new notebook with the environment "ml_skt_book". That worked.

I then checked the packages:
[image: Environment check in jupyter]

On the right you can see that the "ml_skt_book" environment is used. It therefore doesn't make sense that pandas can be imported.

Comment: No screenshots of text or code! Instead copy-paste the text into your question directly.

Answer (score 1):

I think the venv has access to the packages of its 'base' python by default unless you disable it by setting `--system-site-packages` to `false`.

See the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) for details.

###### Edit Mar 1st 2023

I finally figured out how this whole thing works.

Once you run `python -m ipykernel install --name=ml_skt_book`, it actually generate a kernelspec folder named `ml_skt_book` in your home path or jupyter path (the console output tells when you run that). If you forgot, by default it should be in `C:\ProgramData\jupyter\kernels` (windows) or `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels` (linux). Inside the folder there is a `kernel.json` which looks like

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/usr/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "ml_skt_book",
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
```

and that python in `argv` is the python used for the kernel.

So you'll need to check what's in your `kernel.json` and see if it points to the python executable in your ml_skt_book venv, or to the base environment.

According to my experiment, you'll need to run `python -m ipykernel install --name=ml_skt_book` with your venv `ml_skt_book` activated to generate kernelspec with your venv python in `argv`. If you run that command under base environment, it generates kernelspec with name "ml_skt_book" only, but the python executable still the one in base env, that is to say, meaningless.

Also, if you didn't have `ipykernel` installed in your venv, it will complains when you run `python -m ipykernel install --name=ml_skt_book` under it, as the venv doesn't share packages with the base environment. So you need to install again in venv.

Comment: I checked the pyvenv.cfg file in the venv folder. It says:
include-system-site-packages = false ; 
version = 3.9.10 ;
Is there another place where it could be set to true?

Comment: @MartinBiber See my new edits. hopefully can answer your question.

Comment: The argv points to my base python executable. I'm also pretty sure that I connected the venv from the command line without activating the venv before. I'll use your process in the future. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to install Jupyter (`pip install jupyter`) in your desired venv, and then start Jupyter as usual from this venv?
I usually use PyCharm to create venvs and its console for the pip-commands. If I use then Juypter inside those environments, there are only the packages according avaible, which are installed in this venv.
I think the main issue is because you link to the jupyter notebook kernel, which sounds like one from the basic installation of Python on your system.

Comment: This approach didn't change the outcome. I still can access pandas.